# cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command command nginx-rtmp

Tags: windows, nginx, visual-studio-2015, rtmp, cl

I'm installing nginx with rtmp module, using msys and Visual Studio.

When I run `nmake -f objs\makefile` it goes perfectly until I get this error:

> cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command command

I'm using the instructions on [this link](http://www.helping-squad.com/nginx-rtmp-compile-for-windows/) for the step by step configuration, using Windows 7 Professional.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: im currently running in VS 2015 version 14.0